# Values that make matrix positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Assume the symmetric matrix:

$$
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\sigma\omega\pi^2}{4L^2} + g & 0 & -\frac{\sigma + c^2Qg}{2\sigma} \\
    0 & a\mu & -\frac{Q}{2}\left(\frac{c^2}\sigma + g - \mu \right) \\
    -\frac{\sigma + c^2Qg}{2\sigma} & -\frac{Q}{2}\left(\frac{c^2}\sigma + g - \mu \right)& \frac{c^2Q}{\sigma}
  \end{bmatrix}
\
$$
with $\omega \in (0,1)$, $\sigma > 0$, $\mu > 0$.

The objective is to find some values of $Q,a > 0, g \in \mathbb{R}$ that make $M$ positive definite.

### Attempt:

Using Sylvester's criterion, if the determinants:

\begin{align}
d_1 &= \left( \frac{\sigma\omega\pi^2}{4L^2} + g\right)a\mu \\
d_2 &= \left[ \frac{a\mu c^2Q}{\sigma}- \frac{Q^2}{4}\left(\frac{c^2}{\sigma} + g -\mu \right)^2\right]\left( \frac{\sigma \omega \pi^2}{4L^2} + g \right) - a\mu \left(\frac{\sigma + c^2Qg}{2\sigma} \right)^2
\end{align}

are positive then $M$ is positive definite.

$d_1$ is easy to make it positive, for $g = 0$ and $a = 1$ for example. But then, I'm having trouble finding a value for $Q$ such that:

$$
d_2 = \left[ \frac{\mu c^2Q}{\sigma}- \frac{Q^2}{4}\left(\frac{c^2}{\sigma} -\mu \right)^2\right]\frac{\sigma\omega\pi^2}{4L^2} - \frac{\mu}{4} > 0
$$

Any thoughts? Is my initial choice of $g,a$ good?

Comment: Are $\omega, \sigma, \mu$ known? Are they independent? What about $L?$

Comment: @user376343 $\sigma, \mu, L$ are just positive and $\omega \in (0,1)$.

Comment: Your equation $d_2(Q)$ is a quadratic equation in $Q$ with negative leading coefficient, so taking $Q$ as the average of the roots (which is easily found since the sum of the roots is $-b/a$, and assuming the roots are real and distinct) will give $d_2(Q) > 0$.

Comment: @LtSten and for proving that this choice of $Q$ is positive?

Comment: Consider $-\alpha(Q-q_1)(Q-q_2)$ for $\alpha > 0$ and $q_i$ real. Alternatively, it's "trivial" geometrically since an upside-down parabola is positive between its roots (that should be your intuition for this, anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take $g=0$ and $a=Q^2$. Then $d_1$ is obviously positive and
\begin{align}
d_2
&= \left[ \frac{a\mu c^2Q}{\sigma}- \frac{Q^2}{4}\left(\frac{c^2}{\sigma} + g -\mu \right)^2\right]\left( \frac{\sigma \omega \pi^2}{4L^2} + g \right) - a\mu \left(\frac{\sigma + c^2Qg}{2\sigma} \right)^2\\
&= \left[ \frac{\mu c^2Q^3}{\sigma}- \frac{Q^2}{4}\left(\frac{c^2}{\sigma} -\mu \right)^2\right]\left( \frac{\sigma \omega \pi^2}{4L^2} \right) - Q^2\mu \left(\frac{\sigma}{2\sigma} \right)^2\\
&= \frac{\mu c^2Q^3}{\sigma}\left( \frac{\sigma \omega \pi^2}{4L^2} \right) - Q^2\times\text{constant}\\
\end{align}
is positive when $Q>0$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: Interesting approach, but isn't there a way to assign a specific numerical value to $Q$ for which $d_2 > 0$? Any arbitrary value will be suffiecient. Can we find one?.

Comment: @Paris Since $d_2=\alpha Q^3-\beta Q^2$ for some $\alpha,\beta>0$, it suffices to take any $Q>\beta/\alpha$. You can work out the details.